# Is it correct to use categorical inputs in a Neural Network to predict another categorical output?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, binary-data, categorical-encoding

Let's say we want to predict only whether next day's temperature is going up or down (so two classes as opposed to predicting the actual temperature). Would there be any issues with using another binary predictor in the form of "1/-1" for example as an input? And how can such a setup be made even more accurate? (like, would using one-hot encoding increase accuracy as opposed to just inputting 1 and -1 directly etc)

Answer (score 1):

You essentially are describing a binary output (two levels). Neural networks can do that, and other types of outputs.  Neural networks accept either categorical (including binary) or continuous inputs.  These different types of inputs and outputs can be mixed.  You can do manual encoding, however the implementations of neural networks I'm familiar with do the encoding automatically.  There are many implementations of neural networks from different vendors and open sources.

The encoding method won't increase accuracy, however a different encoding *may* address a different question, or it may give the same result depending on the specifics. Manual encoding can be done incorrectly, so be sure you know what you are doing, and how the model works.